# Matching any route using $urlRouterProvider in AngularJS and Angular-UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, intercom

I'm not an AngularJS dev but I was handed a project.

Now I need to call the following method, every time a route changes. doesn't matter to which route, just any route.

```
window.Intercom("update");
```

Now I found the following piece of code.

```
function config($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $translateProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
```

So in that method I have access to the **$urlRouterProvider**, I read in the docs that here it's possible to check for matched routes, even with regex.

> Now I'm wondering, is it possible to see any time the router changes url, Am I looking in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the new Angular UI Router version 1.xx

You could just use a run block like so:

```
angular.module('whatever').run(function($transitions){
    $transitions.onSuccess({}, function(){
        window.Intercom("update");
    });
});
```

If you're using the legacy version of Angular UI Router you could just subscribe to `$stateChangeSuccess` events like so:

```
angular.module('whatever').run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
        window.Intercom("update");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see that $rootscope.$on('$stateChangeStart') is already there.. Is that the place to initialize the plugin? Since I need to initialize it on first run, and then update on the succes thing. Or am I seeing it wrong?

Comment: A `.run()` block executes only once, after the app bootstraps. In this case, it's executing once and adding an event handler. So the `.run()` block runs once, then the callback for the event handler will run every time the state changes.

Comment: Hmh.. almost understanding it, so inside the run() method using the stateChangeStart to init the plugin, and the stateChangeSuccess to update it on every new route isn't going to work?

Comment: What are you using `$stateChangeStart` for? That event will fire before every potential state change. State changes might be prevented, though. `$stateChangeSuccess` only fires if the state actually changes.

Comment: `$stateChangeStart` is usually used to check authentication or access rights and to reject the state change or redirect the user if necessary.

Comment: Well I'm trying to integration Intercom, It's a plugin and they ask "Once he app initializes do the following script", then "Do the other script every time the view and/or URL changes in your app.".. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Right, so the "do once the app initializes" code can be at the top of the `.run()` block and the "do every time the view changes" code should go in the `$stateChangeSuccess` handler.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try and test this. and i'll accept your answer offcourse